# Why does an HTML iframe work properly, but does PHP's include return "file not find?

Tags: php, iframe, include

In PHP, I want to show a static HTML file in the index.php file. When I use `iframe` everything works OK, but I want use the `include` function. I use `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` but the problem remains.
Which differences exist between the HTML `iframe` and PHP's `include`?

Comment: You can only include .php files. change your html file extension to php extension then try again.

Comment: File not found error show again. Image file in included file not find. I know how solve this problem but my question is Which differences exist between the HTML iframe and PHP's include?